# WEBrick CGI handler pointing to wrong gem location

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, webrick

I am trying to execute my CGI program from WEBrick CGIhandler and kept failing with 'loaderror' of gem libraries. Is someone seen following behavior before? How could I get my CGI scripts to search valid gem location?

**[Situaltion]**

When I ran CGI scripts that requires 'mysql2' library via Webrick server, I got a following error:

> ERROR CGIHandler: /home/charles/code/svr/lib/cgitest.rb:
>   /home/charles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/version (LoadError)

Comment this particular 'require' out from cgitest.rb makes this script work so looks just failed to load this library. Added "puts Gem.path" to the script indicates CGIHandler is looking to following directories to find gem;

> ["/home/charles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1", "/.gem/ruby/1.9.1"]

while actual GEM:HOME and GEM:PATH are following;

> ["/home/charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194", "/home/charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global"]

I think I am missing something very simple but could not figure them out. Really appreciate if someone lead me to the right direction. Any input would be highly welcome.

**[Environment]**

Using RVM to install Ruby 1.9.3 to Ubuntu Server 12.4 with bunch of gems including "mysql2" library. And the script can load 'mysql2' when I run from local.

> $which ruby
>
> /home/charles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
>
> $irb
>
> 1.9.3-p194 :001 > Gem.path
>
> => ["/home/charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194", "/home/charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-
>   p194@global"]
>
> 1.9.3-p194 :002 >   require 'mysql2'
>
> => true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use wrapper instead of bin/ruby:

```
/home/charles/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby
```

This will ensure you load proper environment when starting ruby.

Comment: Thanks mpapis, you are awesome! Now all the gems can be loaded as intended.

Comment: @charles you should accept answer if it's solving your problem ;)